# When people purposely answer the question the way the OP says he/she doesn't want it

Tags: discussion, support

When asking [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129891/what-is-the-best-cph-for-blue-charms) I was looking for someone who actually knew about CPH. Now the question is closed and the answers are exactly what I don't want and have even said so. I have had another problem like this on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127212/what-is-a-great-farming-method-for-crimson-charms) but to no avail. I really want legitimate answers. Should these answers and others be deleted if they don't provide the information that the OP specifically says he/she wants?

Comment: The problem is, sometimes the OP asks a question that cannot be sufficiently answered based on the data given. From the sound of it, CPH will vary from character to character, depending on a variety of factors. And these factors can mean that the most efficient target for one person, may not be the the most efficient for another. So, what can an answerer do but attempt to point you in the right direction, and tell you how to arrive at the information you desire (teach a man to fish, rather than give him one)? Their only other option is to give you information that might be factually incorrect.

Answer (score 14):

The thing is, answers aren't meant to help only the asker.  They're meant to help the internet at large; that's one of the core tenets of the StackExchange network.

Insisting on a specific format of answer is something that answers can and should disregard if it's not something that's helpful.  Artificially limiting the people who can answer to only people who meet your criteria isn't something supported by SE at all.

From what I can tell, you're one of the only people around who understands what this whole charms per hour thing is, even by the people here who play Runescape.  Answers shouldn't be limited to only the way the asker wants them, but what is most useful to the internet at large.  A good answer will give you at least an explanation of charms per hour, but there is no obligation for them to do so.

This definition, as best as I can determine, is very dependent on your own personal character.  If there's reference material available (that's not the calculator you already linked to), feel free to point it out.  Providing more background as to what you're looking for can help users understand it better, and give you a better chance of getting an answer in the way you want it.

Comment: Adding to this, there are two mechanisms available to you to deal with answers that you have a problem with:

**The downvote button:** Use this if it attempts to answer the question, but you do not find the answer accurate or useful.

**The flag button:** Use this when the answer does not even attempt to answer the question, such as when someone leaves spam, asks their own question, tries to comment on another answer, etc.

Comment: As well as fbueckert's answer, you **really** don't help yourself by hassling and threatening people's answers as you did [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127212/what-is-a-great-farming-method-for-crimson-charms).  You might not have heard but we're trying to [be nice to each other](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/lets-be-nice-to-each-other)

Comment: However if the answer I want isn't given then it isn't the acceptable answer.

Comment: @YoungGuilo You're conflating answer acceptance with acceptable answers.  Nobody but you can can accept an answer, but that doesn't mean an answer has to meet your criteria to actually be an answer.  So long as a good faith attempt is made to answer the question, it's an acceptable answer, regardless of whatever the asker specifies as criteria.

Comment: @Sterno there's a third.  If he wanted someone to work for an answer suited his way, he can always offer a bounty.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I 100% agree that you do not have to click the check box marking an answer as accepted if you do not think it solves your problem.

Comment: @spartacus Just like the green checkmark, askers are welcome to set bounties with whatever criteria they want. They're still not guaranteed that they'll get the answer they want.

Answer (score 9):

I voted to close because the question lacks fundamental data necessary to answer it in the way you ask. The problem is not that you're asking for it to be answered in a very specific way, the problem is that you're asking for something that requires knowledge we can only have by going to your house and using your computer.

You're effectively asking "What colour are my pants? I can't see them, please tell me. Specific RGB codes, please." The request for specific RGB codes is not the problem, as you are assuming; the problem is that we can't see your pants either.

Comment: The whole point of a Q/A site is for that. Questions and answers. I'm looking for a specific answer. When people who know what I'm talking about see the question they'll answer it. My pants are camo and would never ask anything so meaningless as that.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I don't know how to respond to that except by repeating what I just wrote. I suppose, "Not every question that can be asked has an answer."